# i want to display highest no. of episodes

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, sql-order-by

I have the following code

```
SELECT PRESENTERS.PNRFNAME, PRESENTERS.PNRLNAME, 
COUNT(EPISODES.PRESENTERID) AS "no. of episodes"
FROM EPISODES
JOIN PRESENTERS
ON EPISODES.PRESENTERID=PRESENTERS.PRESENTERID
GROUP BY PRESENTERS.PNRFNAME, PRESENTERS.PNRLNAME
ORDER BY COUNT(EPISODES.PRESENTERID)
```

[image: these are the results]

I tried adding

```
HAVING COUNT(EPISODES.PRESENTERID) > 2
```

[image: These are the results]

But I have to pretend like I haven't seen how many no. of episode are there.is there other way I can display row that have more no. of episode?

Comment: What if there's a tie for 1st place?

Comment: You accepted the answer with the query of `TOP 1`. Are you using `MySQL` or `SQL-Server` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    select top 1 PRESENTERS.PNRFNAME, PRESENTERS.PNRLNAME,COUNT(EPISODES.PRESENTERID) AS "no. of episodes" FROM EPISODES JOIN PRESENTERS ON EPISODES.PRESENTERID=PRESENTERS.PRESENTERID GROUP BY PRESENTERS.PNRFNAME, PRESENTERS.PNRLNAME ORDER BY COUNT(EPISODES.PRESENTERID) desc;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want only the rows with the highest number of episodes, you can add this at the end of your query (and remove the `HAVING`, it is useless):

```
ORDER BY `no. of episodes` DESC
LIMIT 1
```

The idea: you sort your rows so that the records with the most episodes are at the top, then you limit your results to a certain number (here 1).

What you missed was the `DESC` keyword, since by default order by sorts from low to high (`ASC`, ascending).

Comment: Use backtick instead of double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need the `having` you just need to `order by COUNT(EPISODES.PRESENTERID) DESC` and that should give you high to low

Comment: I want a row with highest no. of episode

Answer (score 0):

By default MySQL sorts rows in ascending order. you need to tell it explicitly to sort it in descending order.

```
SELECT PRESENTERS.PNRFNAME, PRESENTERS.PNRLNAME, 
COUNT(EPISODES.PRESENTERID) AS "no. of episodes"
FROM EPISODES
JOIN PRESENTERS
ON EPISODES.PRESENTERID=PRESENTERS.PRESENTERID
GROUP BY PRESENTERS.PNRFNAME, PRESENTERS.PNRLNAME
ORDER BY COUNT(EPISODES.PRESENTERID) DESC;
```

Above will give you all the rows in descending orbelowder,however if you want only one row with highest count of `episodes` you could just do `limit 1`

```
SELECT PRESENTERS.PNRFNAME, PRESENTERS.PNRLNAME, 
COUNT(EPISODES.PRESENTERID) AS "no. of episodes"
FROM EPISODES
JOIN PRESENTERS
ON EPISODES.PRESENTERID=PRESENTERS.PRESENTERID
GROUP BY PRESENTERS.PNRFNAME, PRESENTERS.PNRLNAME
ORDER BY COUNT(EPISODES.PRESENTERID) DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply append `DESC` with your current query , there you have !

```
SELECT        PRESENTERS.PNRFNAME, PRESENTERS.PNRLNAME, COUNT(EPISODES.PRESENTERID) AS [no. of episodes]
FROM            EPISODES INNER JOIN
                         PRESENTERS ON EPISODES.PRESENTERID = PRESENTERS.PRESENTERID
GROUP BY PRESENTERS.PNRFNAME, PRESENTERS.PNRLNAME
ORDER BY [no. of episodes] DESC
```

**Desired output :**

[image]

To select Top 1 :

```
SELECT        TOP (1) PRESENTERS.PNRFNAME, PRESENTERS.PNRLNAME, COUNT(EPISODES.PRESENTERID) AS [no. of episodes]
FROM            EPISODES INNER JOIN
                         PRESENTERS ON EPISODES.PRESENTERID = PRESENTERS.PRESENTERID
GROUP BY PRESENTERS.PNRFNAME, PRESENTERS.PNRLNAME
ORDER BY [no. of episodes] DESC
```